# Update or Change Element/Value without refreshing web page jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I've created a playlist using JWPlayer, also using cookie to remember position of played video until I can database it. Here is an example of my code:

Need to update the $resume without refreshing page?

$vid = '5';

$vRow = $dbObj->getRowFromDB("select * from table where ID='$vid'");

$resume = $vRow['ID'];

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jwplayer("video").setup({
            flashplayer:'jwplayer.swf',
            aboutlink:'<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>',
            file:'<?= $path; ?>',
            image:'<?= $vid; ?>',
            stretching:'uniform',
            controlbar:true,
            width:'100%',
            aspectratio:'16:9',
            start:false,
            }).onReady(function(){
                 jwPlayerResumable.init('<?= $resume; ?>').resumePlayBack({
                    aftertime:10,
                    divtoshow:['.hide']
                });
            }).onTime(function(event) {
                if(event.position > 10) {
                    $('.hide').show();
                }
            });      
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: "Update" it where? On the page, in the cookie, in the database, in your javascript function? Please be more specific

Comment: Sorry, using data already supplied by the $vRow statement on click from JWPlayer's playlist next video if possible? the <?= $resume; ?> under onReady(function(){  jwPlayerResumable.init('<?= $resume; ?>').resumePlayBack({aftertime:10,
                    divtoshow:['.hide']
                });

Comment: Whoops hit the enter key to early, when the page is created all of the playlist is generated, my remember where we left off uses cookies so each video is tagged by user and id encoded 64 just for appearance, my question is can we update on click of next movie in list then updating the $resume location or value which intern would cookie the next and so on? Thanks

Comment: Closing this question because so much time has passed and the question posted may not be interpreted properly. Thanks